# Como traduzir um programa em C para Assembly?

Tags: c, assembly

Como faço a interação entre as duas linguagens?

Comment: Qual é o programa? Aproveite e faça um [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) no site para aprender mais sobre como aumentar suas chances de ter sua dúvida esclarecida.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No compilador da Microsoft é usado a [opção `/FA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fa-fa-listing-file?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=msvc-170).

No GCC [usa-se `-S`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options).

Quanto à "interação" depende do problema, faça outra pergunta mais específica.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).